# Function with function as parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I'm trying to define a function that should call a(nother) function that is passed as parameter of the main function.

```
function showMessage(title, text, button, callback) {

    console.log(title, text, button);

    if (typeof (callback) != "function") {
        function callback() {};
        alert("converted callback");
    }

    $("div").click( function() {
        callback();
    });

}

function myfunction() {
    alert("function!");
}

showMessage("title", "text", "button", myfunction() );
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XvE8D/1/

The problem is that when `showMessage()` function is called, `myfunction()` is called istantly.

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: It is called instantly because you are calling it. :) `myfunction() <-- ()` says run!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you've observed, `myfunction()` with parentheses invokes `myfunction`.

Try passing `myfunction` to `showMessage` without parentheses:

```
showMessage("title", "text", "button", myfunction);
```

Also, in `showMessage` you'll have to change this part:

```
if (typeof (callback) != "function") {
    function callback() {};
    alert("converted callback");
}
```

To this:

```
if (typeof (callback) != "function") {
    callback = function() {};
    alert("converted callback");
}
```

To pass additional parameters to `myfunction`, you can wrap `myfunction` in another function and pass that to `showMessage`. Something like this should work:

```
showMessage("title", "text", "button", function() { myfunction('foo'); });
```

Comment: thanks but what if I need to pass params to the callback? Do I need to pass them first to the showMessage and then pass them to the callback?

Comment: @FezVrasta That depends. Are the parameters to the callback known at the time you call `showMessage` or are they only known when the user clicks the element?

Comment: Thanks, I've used the $.noop from @Arun P Johny's answer and the rest from yours.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass a function reference as the callback argument, in your case you are invoking the function and is assigning the value returned by `myfunction`(in this case undefined) as the callback argument.

Also see the use [$.noop()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noop/)

```
function showMessage(title, text, button, callback) {   
    console.log(title, text, button);

    callback = callback || $.noop;

    $("div").click(function(){
        callback('my params')
    });
}

function myfunction() {
    alert("function!");
}

showMessage("title", "text", "button", myfunction);
```

Comment: What if I need to pass a parameter to myfunction?

Comment: Ok so I need to pass the params of the function as separated params of the showMessage function right?